# Kafka best practicies - apply the deduplication before record deserialization

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

**Use case**
There is an upstream system producing the data batches through Kafka (one batch has 10 millions of records on average). 
Start offset and expected records count goes through one topic (control), and data itself goes through another (data).
It is possible that periodically some records will get duplicated when the batch is produced, making the expected record not match the one sent on the control topic.
Each record has unique id.

**Problem**
With the duplicates not included in expected records count, I don't really know when to stop processing the data. Also, I would like to skip those duplicated records before deserialization, to speed up the processing.

**Proposed solution**
I proposed to send the record id in Kafka header so that on the consumer side I will keep the ids for the particular batch in hashset and check if the record is the duplicate or new one.

Compacted log is not an option as the consumer starts to consume the records before the producer stops producing it, so there is anyway the chanse that the duplicates will pop up.

**Question**
I heard that it is the anti-pattern to send the id in header per each record, but I wanted to understand if it really is (and why).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> keep the ids for the particular batch in hashset

Hashsets are not distributed, and will not be maintained if a consumer process crashes, and needs restarted.

You therefore would need an external, persistent cache like Redis, Hazelcast, etc.

---

Headers can have whatever value you want, but they themselves still need deserialized. They certainly are not an anti-pattern.

I've had co-workers use a combination of Cassandra or MongoDB with Elasticsearch to prevent processing of duplicate IDs, which can happen not only from a producer, but also from consumer rebalancing with a lack of offset commits. They did use headers to track that information, but obviously, it adds latency to the consumer, so you need to increase `max.poll.interval.ms` or lower `max.poll.records`.

Comment: There is no need for the idempotency keys to be stored in the distributed storage. In the solution which I implemented, single process is responsible for the processing of the single batch (duplicates are only checked within batch). Also in case of failure, I have the all-or-nothing approach, so basically in case of failure during batch processing, none of the records from that batch will be committed so another process will start processing from the beginning.

Comment: Seems like that'll realistically only work if you have one partition, or as you said, one consumer for many partitions

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have a big amount of data that need to be processed all together, a classic batch - batch implementation. Why are you using Kafka for that? Splitting data in to multiple messages creates an event dependency, which is in deed an antipattern, with a very painful solution.
Have you considered using another pattern, for example create the data in a file in a bucket and send the Bucket URL thru kafka message. This way, you get rid of duplicated data (but you can't star consuming until all records are written in the bucket). Many times, it is still faster.

If that's not useful, and you still need/prefer your pattern, what you need is to build an idempotency, this is a great explanation: https://www.lydtechconsulting.com/blog-kafka-idempotent-consumer.html
As you can see, more processing is needed.

About the Headers, yes you can, it is indeed the building standard (you could follow the [Cloud Events](https://github.com/cloudevents/spec/blob/v1.0.2/cloudevents/bindings/kafka-protocol-binding.md) standard), but I don't think you would win much time, normally messages are not duplicated. This use case is great if you are going to build a filter and deprecate most of the message, and that is not your case.